# Create a ComboBox containing the values of a checked CheckBoxs

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, combobox

I am creating a list of `CheckBox`s and a `ComboBox` that contains the list of checked checkboxes in WPF MVVM application. I don't know how to bind in text of combobox checked values from checkboxes.

Here is what I have tried:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Systems}" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" 
    IsEditable="True" IsReadOnly="True" Text="{}">
     <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
        <CheckBox Content="{Binding TemplateName}" IsChecked="{Binding 
          IsSystemChecked, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
       </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: Could you rephrase what you are trying to do please?

Comment: My question is when user will check to checkbox how item should display in combobox

Comment: So you want a list of checkboxs and combobox that contains the list of checked checkboxes?

Comment: yes I want exactly that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
<StackPanel>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Systems}" >
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <CheckBox Content="{Binding TemplateName}" IsChecked="{Binding 
                    IsSystemChecked, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>

    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Systems}" DisplayMemberPath="TemplateName" >
        <ComboBox.Style>
            <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ComboBoxItem}}">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSystemChecked}" Value="False">
                                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ComboBox.Style>
    </ComboBox>
</StackPanel>
```

Here there is:

- `ListView` containing a checkbox for each item in `Systems` which is bound to to the `IsSystemChecked` property
- `ComboBox` containing all of the items in `Systems` however if the `IsSystemChecked` property is false the `Visibility` is set to `Collapsed` so it is not displayed

Let me know if you have any issues! Hope this helps.